# Variable is not pickable error with scheduler="processes" when using dask.array from netcdf file

Tags: python, dask, netcdf

I'm trying to use dask to process 3-dimensional arrays (x, y, time). These arrays are stored as netcdf4 files and have been written using the netCDF4 python library. I am able to create a dask.array from a variable defined within my netcdf file, when I try to compute a result using scheduler="processes" the following error is raised:

```py
NotImplementedError: Variable is not picklable
```

I am aware that [parallel writing is not supported when using dask with netcdf](https://github.com/SciTools/iris/issues/3157), however the error is raised during a simple computation of the mean along the time axis. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825150/notimplementederror-x-is-not-picklable) seems related, but does not help to solve my problem. Computing the mean along the time axis is just for demonstration purpose. In practice I will apply more complex functions which are only partially based on numpy, which is why I want to sidestep Python's Global Interpreter Lock by using processes in dask.

```py
import dask.array as da
import netCDF4

path = 'path/to/netcdf_file'
dset = netCDF4.Dataset(path, 'r')
var = dset['var']

x = da.from_array(var, chunks=(500, 500, 2))
dset.close()

result = da.mean(x, axis=2)

# raises NotImplementedError: Variable is not picklable
result.compute(scheduler="processes")

# works just fine
result.compute(scheduler="threads")
```

Why does `.compute(scheduler="processes")` raise an error and what are possible solutions? Since I have many files in netcdf4 format, I would like to avoid having to convert everything to another file format.

I am running Python 2.7 (miniconda distribution) on CentOS 7. Dask v1.1.4 and netCDF4 v1.4.3.2 have been installed from conda-forge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Dask's multiprocessing scheduler (e.g. `scheduler="processes"`), process will need to handle opening and accessing the netCDF data individually. I would strongly suggest trying to use Xarray for this task as it has built in support for working with netCDF and Dask. I've written out an equivalent workflow using Xarray/Dask/netCDF4 below:

```
import dask
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('path/to/netcdf_file',
                     engine='netcdf4',
                     chunks={'x': 500, 'y': 500, 'z': 2})

with dask.config.set(scheduler='processes'):
    result = ds['var'].mean(dim='z').load()
```

[Xarray's documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html) has a nice page discussing how to use dask in this context.